# extraer dos variables para compararlos en un if

Tags: php, variables

quiero limitar la entrada de datos a bd, cuando sea menor o igual que 10 filas y comparar dos campos (capacidad, maxima_capacidad) entre si para que cuando el valor sea el mismo poder a posteriori capar el botón de envio.
Depurando el código en javascript veo que solo me coje el primer condicionante el segundo se lo salta y me sigue dando true

```
if(isset($_POST['consulta']))
{
    $q = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM coches WHERE `username`='$username' and `status`='$status'");    
    $consulta = mysqli_num_rows($q);  
    if ($consulta<=9 && ($consulta['max_capacidad']==$consulta['capacidad']))
    {
        echo "true";
    }
    else{
        echo "false";
    }
}
```

---

Este es el codigo que quiero limitar con los campos de max_capacidad y capacidad

```
else if(isset($_POST['consulta'])){
    $reg_id=$_POST['reg_id'];

    $q=mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE `coches` SET capacidad = capacidad+1 WHERE `reg_id`='$reg_id'");
    if($q){
        echo "true";
    }
    else
        echo "false";
}
```

---

No consigo hacerlo, la comparación no me funciona, sigue dandome siempre true

```
else if(isset($_POST['consulta'])){
    $reg_id=$_POST['reg_id'];
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    

$q = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM coches WHERE `username`='$username' and `status`='$status'");

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($q);

    $capacidad=$row['capacidad'];
    $max_capacidad=$row['max_capacidad'];

    if ($max_capacidad==$capacidad){
    echo "true";

    if($q){
        echo "true";
    }
    else
        echo "false";
}
else
        echo "false";
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! $consulta ni puede tener un numero y datos... o si?

Comment: me parece que te falta un fetch_array en tu variable $consulta solo extraes el num_rows , pero no las variables:   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($q), también si quieres usar menor o igual a 10 debes usar <=10 de lo contrario estas haciendo menor igual a 9 o en su defecto usa <11.

Answer (score 0):

Te he cambiado un poco la estructura, en principio veo dos errores, uno, se te olvido `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` para obtener tus datos y luego también debes eliminar `()` en tu sentencia `if`, quedaría así, `if ($consulta <= 9 && $consulta['max_capacidad'] == $consulta['capacidad'])`.

**Posible ejemplo:**

```
if(isset($_POST['consulta'])) {
    
    //Importante obtener tus parametros a pasar...
    $username = ...;
    $status = ....;

    //Consulta
    $q = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM coches WHERE `username`='$username' and `status`='$status'");           
    
    //Verdadero consulta
    if ($q) {

        //Registros.
        $filas = mysqli_num_rows($q); 

        //Comprobar Registros
        if ($filas<=9) {
            //Obtenemos datos
            while ($consulta = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
                //Comprobamos columnas.
                if ($consulta['max_capacidad'] == $consulta['capacidad']) {
                    echo "true";
                } else{
                    echo "false";
                }
            }
            
        }
        // No cumple con los registros
        else{
            echo "false";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Fallo la consulta";
    }
}
```

Te aconsejo usar [sentencias preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), para mejor la seguridad.